# Jeet Framework: Why does the fixed menu getting slower and slower in Firefox latest for Windows XP?

Tags: css-frameworks

Since It seem to be important to ask a question in Stack Overflow, I ask. But it's more like a comment: The Jeet fixed-menu example http://jeetframework.com/demo/fixed_nav/ are getting very slow in Firefox latest for Windows XP. The first time I scroll the page it is as fast at suspected, but after two or three scrolls it starts to get slower and slower. It is all OK in Chrome latest.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** Decoupled and refactored the whole thing. Hope you like it. Works perfect in Jeet and smooth in all browsers down to IE7+: https://github.com/CorySimmons/relatively-sticky

---

Thanks for asking. First off, you're exactly right. I'm not great at JS so I tested this on all the browsers as I was developing it and it seemed fine, then I just stopped testing it on Firefox for the last leg of it's development and went ahead and pushed it, then I investigated it in Firefox and exactly as you say, theres some event bubbling or some leak that is causing it to be broken.

I had already opened a ticket for this here: https://github.com/CorySimmons/jeet/issues/68

And although I really appreciate you asking questions about Jeet on Stack (as it helps get our community out there a little bit), I think this is a prime example of something that should be reported as a bug in the issue tracker.

Feel free to +1 this issue https://github.com/CorySimmons/jeet/issues/68

I'll be refactoring it within the next week if I can find time. Rest assured it won't be ignored for long though.